# How to get select option id value in form api

Tags: forms

Hi hello please help how to get dynamically selected option id value (i.e `#options=>0=>'bala',1=>'kumar'`)

for example 
how to get selected value of ID value in form api in drupal

```
$form['state1']= array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('State'),
  '#options' =>$options_state,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
    'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
  ),
);
```

the selected value store in $key value, please help me how to do....

```
$key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']) ? $form_state['values']['state1'] : 1;
```

is this correct???

Comment: a value store in $key variable

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: What makes you think it _isn't_ correct?

Comment: for example (1001->india,1002->usa) like that stored in select option value (india, usa like that) , but i want to fetch the id value(1001, 1002) of selected value of id value from option? that value to be store in $key variable, please help me

Comment: ya i have tried but i cant fetch that value please help me

Comment: im confused, do you want the key or the value ? the value is always available in the form and the results.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value using:

```
$form['field_name'][#options][$form_state['values']['field_name']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get selected value of that select box using $form_state like this

ex: If you want to use that id in your callback "_ajaxfunction" then its possible using $form_state variable.

`$key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']['und']['value']) ? $form_state['values']['state1']['und']['value'] : 1;`

or

`$key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']['und']['nid']) ? $form_state['values']['state1']['und']['nid'] : 1;`

still not work then print bellow line and you will get perfect array

`$form_state['values']['state1']['und']`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fields API:

You can get the Value of the `key => value` pair of a Select List by using `list_allowed_values()` see the [docs page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_allowed_values/7) for more info.

Your form will always return the key in the result so you can do something like this :

```
$key = $form_state['values']['whatever'];
$options = list_allowed_values("field_whatever");
$value = $options[$key];
```